# pass JSON string to create tag React.createelement

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a JSON string created by API:

```
var appStructure = {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Register Form Loaded.",
    "response": "'div',{},'Registration'"
};
```

I want to create element dynamically using the API `response`. I am trying to do something like this:

```
var testCard1 = React.createElement(appStructure.response);
ReactDOM.render(testCard1, document.getElementById('main-content'));
```

But it keep giving me the error

> Warning:  is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
>   Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('h1',{},'Hello Testing') is not a valid name.

Answer (score 2):

`appStructure.response` is string and can't be passed into `createElement` method as arguments. You should change string to acceptable arguments. Also `testCard1` should be in PascalCase: `TestCard1`

```
var args = appStructure.response.split(',');
var TestCard1= React.createElement(args[0].replace(/\W/g, ''), JSON.parse(args[1]), args[2].replace(/\W/g, ''));
```

Comment: Thanks. I have another issue, i am creating form and inputes using api response but form tag is closed just after open, i want that form tag should close at the last input button. I am using React.createElement in loop and applying this state on all inputes coming, so everything is working fine but form tag is closed at the time of open and other inputes are placed outside that form